# compare function, all columns TRUE but overall FALSE

Tags: r

I compared two datasets with 24 columns and 71 observations. These datasets come from a comparison between the following two functions (I can't reproduce th file since it is 10000 obsrvations):

```
# stats package
x = aggregate(x = Survey_Clean[-ncol(Survey_Clean)], 
by = list(Survey$info_county), FUN = "mean", na.rm=TRUE)


# dplyr package
x1 = Survey_Clean[-ncol(Survey_Clean)] %>%
  group_by(Survey$info_county) %>%
  summarise_all(mean,na.rm = TRUE)
```

The outcome of the compare package (Package compare version 0.2-6 Index) is as follows. How is this possible? I mean if all are TRUE it should be TRUE right?

```
compare(x, x1)

FALSE [TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE]
```

If I then cut the two datasets by one observations, the output is:

```
x = x[1:70,]
x1 = x[1:70,]
compare(x, x1)
TRUE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It must be related to the `tibble` attribute from 'x1'.  if we convert to `data.frame`, it should work

```
library(compare)
compare(x, as.data.frame(x1))
#[1] TRUE
```

By default, some of the arguments are  set as `FALSE` i.e. `allowAll` -

> allowAll = FALSE)

If we change it to `TRUE`, it could automatically do the transformation by dropping the attributes

```
compare(x, x1, allowAll = TRUE)
```

---

Using a small reproducible example

```
library(dplyr)
data(iris)
x <- aggregate(.~ Species, iris, mean, na.rm = TRUE)
x1 <- iris %>% 
         group_by(Species) %>% 
         summarise_all(mean, na.rm = TRUE)
compare(x, x1)
#FALSE [TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE] #// similar to OP's output
```

Now, do the `compare` again after converting the `tibble`

```
str(x1)
#tibble [3 × 5] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
# $ Species     : Factor w/ 3 levels "setosa","versicolor",..: 1 2 3
# $ Sepal.Length: num [1:3] 5.01 5.94 6.59
# $ Sepal.Width : num [1:3] 3.43 2.77 2.97
# $ Petal.Length: num [1:3] 1.46 4.26 5.55
# $ Petal.Width : num [1:3] 0.246 1.326 2.026


compare(x, as.data.frame(x1))
#TRUE
```

Or use `allowAll = TRUE` to do all the transformations required

```
compare(x, x1, allowAll = TRUE)
#TRUE
```